# java.lang.NullPointerException: while try accessing textview from viewholder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a custom `RecycleView` and I am able to display the data in the `RecycleView`successfully. Now, I want to access the text view from the custom layout in order to make the change in later part of my code. I have provided the layout, `RecycleView`adapter and the method I have tried to access the `TextView`. But I am getting `NullPointerException` with the view is null. How can I access the textview((R.id.zb) from `Mylayout.xml` in my main activity to modify `RecycleView` items?

My layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/card_view1"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/z">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Z "
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large.Inverse"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/zn"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="buy"
        android:textColor="#333"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sell"
        android:textColor="#333"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse"/>

</LinearLayout>

 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

RecycleView Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.Viewholder> {

private List<dispitems> m;


@NonNull
@Override
public Adapter.Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list1, parent, false);
    return new Viewholder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.Viewholder holder, int position) {
    dispitems d = m.get(position);
    holder.zb.setText(d.getZb());
    holder.zs.setText(d.getZs());
    holder.zn.setText(d.getZn());
 }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return m.size();

}

Adapter(List<dispitems> m) {
    this.m = m;
}


public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView zb,zs,zn;

    Viewholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        zn = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.zn);
        zb = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.zb);
        zs = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.zs);

    }
}
}
```

I've tried the below options but it is showing the null pointer exception

```
Adapter.Viewholder row = (Adapter.Viewholder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(getCategoryPos(device));

row.zs.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
```

I have received the following exception.

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView cti.cryptotrackerindia.Adapter$Viewholder.zsell' on a null object reference
```

tried the below as well

```
 View row = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(getCategoryPos(device));
```

Comment: try this **`View row = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(0);`**

Comment: View row = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(getCategoryPos(device));
        TextView textView = row.findViewById(R.id.zs;
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));   tried this but nullpointer exception again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not getting the question, but you should be able to just get the textview on onCreateViewHolder after you inflated the view.

```
public Adapter.Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.list1, parent, false);
    TextView txtView = (TextView )itemView.findViewById(R.id.zb);
    return new Viewholder(itemView);
}
```

and then just store it as a member in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update data displayed in RecyclerView, you should use  [`notifyItemChanged(position, payload)`](http://If%20you%20want%20to%20update%20data%20displayed%20in%20RecyclerView,%20you%20should%20use%20%60notifyItemChanged(position,%20payload)%60%20[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object)%20to%20perdorm.) to perform partial re-bind of `ViewHolder`.

Modifying layout of `ViewHolder` directly without referencing represented data can lead to discrepancy in displayed views, especially when You start scrolling your list and `ViewHolder`s start being recycled and reused for other items.